# how to run fermat test on large numbers

Tags: prime-numbers, primality-test, pseudoprimes

fermat test is a primality test, says     that:

if $a^{N-1} \equiv 1\mod N$,

then N in is probably prime, but I have searched for any program that allows me to run this test on large numbers (about 1 million digits), and I have found no programs that can deal with these large numbers, so:

could any body tell me what to do ? and I am sorry if this question is duplicated.

Note that the factories of $N-1$ are known.

Comment: if factoring $N-1$ were helpful you could do it in steps...

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee yes sir, the factories are known, what do you mean, in steps ?

Comment: $(a^b)^c=a^{bc}$

Comment: got it, thank you sir

Comment: See [isFermatPP](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/arithmoi-0.10.0.0/docs/Math-NumberTheory-Primes-Testing.html) Haskell function.

Comment: Also you can use PARI/GP...see [here](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJzzszU2tOZKtDWy5spM08jJTCvR8M1P0UjU8dOM0_DTNdTUtLU11Ckoyswr0VAKKMpPSkzKqVQA8nNTFZU0YRLO-bkF-cWZJSAxTWsAAmwZQA==&lang=gp&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==).

Comment: I am grateful for this comment sir, thank you very much, it helped me a lot.

Comment: For such large numbers I would suggest you to use [OpenPFGW](https://sourceforge.net/projects/openpfgw/).

Comment: @PeđaTerzić pari/gp not very bad, I rather it than openpfgw, thank you sir

Comment: @عبدالرحمنرمزيمحمود You are welcome.

Comment: @PeđaTerzić hi sir, do you have any idea about how to write lucas lehmer primality test in pari gp ? sorry for annoying.

Comment: [Lucas-Lehmer test](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxtiTEOwjAQBHu_InJlQyzFhu7YJ7i6Pk0SxEkEnxJLfJ97ANXOzihu5Bh3chVl1pTJLf2Azfcl7y3YeUBTGRm1rYEvbFwjmb8iR3LyDAxMox7y6cGX2atPeZBzMLNvPv4pS9u1ndKtRvoBOp4lKg==&lang=gp&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==)

Comment: @PeđaTerzić actually, I am very grateful to you sir, thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a simple `C` program using `gmp` ([link](https://gmplib.org)) for manipulating large integers. This is a well-maintained library for these kind of operations. Of course get a C-compiler too (there are many free ones), using Linux is the easiest option, and get enough RAM for your PC. `gmp` already has a pseudo-prime test as a library function that does more than just Fermat tests.

Comment: thanks for your help sir

Comment: I am sorry for disturbing you, but I need some help, I visited gmp website, but didn't know how to download any version, and I have found versions with 2 mb size, is this the program or not

Comment: @عبدالرحمنرمزيمحمود It's a library you have to install on your system. Precise instructions depend on the platform (Windows/Mac OS/Linux etc.). See https://gmplib.org/manual/Installing-GMP.html#Installing-GMP etc.

Comment: thank you very much sir

Answer (score 1):

You need to combine [exponentiation by squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) with [multiplication using Fast Fourier Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_algorithm#Fourier_transform_methods). The first of these is relatively easy to implement; the second is difficult. But without FFT multiplication your program will be impossibly slow.

Comment: thank you, sir.